e2fsck prompts for inode optimization: safe to proceed?
I am trying to utilize e2fsck but it produces the following:
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/vgtrisquel/home
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode <number> extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize<y>?

It continues to show many other Inodes that could be shorter.
Should I say yes to optimizing all of them? Does this have any potential issues? The data on this drive has been backed up.
Thank you so much for any support you can provide.
